# Update animation of MapViewAnnotation (MapBoxSDK IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapbox

I create small animation to move Text() element which acts like a marker trough route. The problem is that currently marker is not moving smoothly, part .onAppear() is not working, but i don't know how i can make it. Can you please give solution for this problem?

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Map(initialViewport: .camera(center: cord, zoom: 8)) {
            // Route polyline
            PolylineAnnotationGroup {
                PolylineAnnotation(id: "route", lineCoordinates: routeCoordinates)
                    .lineColor("#57A9FB")
                    .lineWidth(10)
            }
            // Animated marker
            if let markerCoordinate = markerCoordinate {
                MapViewAnnotation(coordinate: markerCoordinate) {
                    Text("")
                        .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                        .scaleEffect(selected ? 1.8 : 1)
                        .padding(selected ? 20 : 10)
                        .background(
                            Circle().fill(selected ? .red : .blue))
                        .animation(.spring(), value: selected)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selected.toggle()
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 3.0)) {
                                
                            }
                        }
                }
                .allowOverlap(allowOverlap)
            }
        }
    private func animateMarkerAlongRoute() {
    guard !routeCoordinates.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    var index = 0
    let animationDuration: TimeInterval = 1.0
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: animationDuration, repeats: true) { timer in
        guard index < routeCoordinates.count else {
            timer.invalidate()
            isAnimating = false
            return
        }
            markerCoordinate = routeCoordinates[index]
        index += 1
    }
}
```